How to make my go function decrypt information encrypted by c# function?
I have an C# function how encrypt an string and save in postgree. But, now i need in GO take that encrypted string and decrypt. But i have a problem who doesn't work.
This is my C# function:
public string EncryptAES(string cipherText, string password)
{
    var secret = GetSecret("AES-secret");
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);

    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(cipherTextBytes, 0, cipherTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

And this is my golang function:
func EncryptAES(cipherText, password string) (string, error) {
    secret := getSecret("AES-secret")
    salt := []byte(secret)

    cipherTextBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cipherText)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), salt, 1000, 32, sha1.New)
    iv := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), salt, 1000, 16, sha1.New)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    plainTextBytes := make([]byte, len(cipherTextBytes))
    mode.CryptBlocks(plainTextBytes, cipherTextBytes)

    plainText := strings.TrimRight(string(plainTextBytes), "\x00")

    return plainText, nil
}

Anyone can help me?
I really need that function in golang decrypt the information. The C# function is an old function and change her will give my troubles

Please provide sample inputs and outputs to show the problem.

Why do you call the data cipherText when encrypting, that is the plaintext. And why do you call the encryption function EncryptAES on the Go side if you want to decrypt, that should be DecryptAES. If you want to confuse the reader, you've done it! Incidentally, the g/GetSecret() functions are missing.

The bug is probably in the key derivation: In .NET GetBytes(32) returns the first 32 bytes and a subsequent GetBytes(16) returns the 16 bytes that follow the first 32 bytes. In the Go code you should therefore determine 32+16 bytes and use the first 32 bytes as key and the remaining 16 bytes as IV.
